# Difference between -c and -wi paramters of LIBSVM

Tags: libsvm

I have an unbalanced data and I want to use LIBSVM from MATLAB. LIBSVM has two different parameters for cost: -c and -wi. What is the difference between them?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Matlab code

Answer (score 1):

`-c` sets the *global* misclassification penalty whereas `-wi` lets you set a multiplicative coefficient in the misclassification penalty for class `i`. For example: `-c 1 -w1 2` means the misclassification penalty for all classes is 1, except for class 1 where it is $2\times1=2$.